# Send click to background window relative position in panel with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mouse, background-process, sendmessage

I use C#, i have an app with a button1, button2 and a panel1, if i click to button1 it open an external program to panel1, then if i click to button2 it send a background click to the window, works fine.
But the problem is this click position is not relative to the panel and not go to right place. It send the click where are the cursor actually.

Code pieces what i use for that:

```
PerformRightClick(proc.MainWindowHandle, new Point(54, 42));
```

```
void PerformRightClick(IntPtr hwnd, Point point)
{
     var pointPtr = MakeLParam(point.X, point.Y);
     SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
     SendMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
     SendMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
}
```

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
IntPtr MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my test, we need to use `panel.Handle` when we want to send click to panel.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
private const Int32 WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;

        private const Int32 WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
        private const Int32 WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        IntPtr MakeLParam(int x, int y) => (IntPtr)((y << 16) | (x & 0xFFFF));

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformRightClick(panel1.Handle, new Point(20, 30));
        }

        void PerformRightClick(IntPtr hwnd, Point point)
        {
            var pointPtr = MakeLParam(point.X, point.Y);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, pointPtr);
        }

        private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Panel is clicked");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PerformRightClick(this.Handle, new Point(20, 30));
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Form is clicked");
        }
```

Pic:

[image]

Like the above picture, when we click button1, the panel is clicked and the Form is clicked when we click button2.

Comment: Dear Jack,
First off all thanks for you time and tests! As i said with my bad english the clicing is OK. The program send the click but the position is not good. It always send the click to the current mouse position not the set position with lparam, maybe the lparam is wrong or i don't know.

Comment: @Laszlo, how do you check if the position is not good? Have you checked my code? Please try the above code first, then you can tell me what is wrong with you.

Comment: Jack, I tested in my code with:
`private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y));
        }`
Then i used this code on your source and i get the good coordiante so it works. I do something wrong.